# raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : josephus.adb:50 index check failed

Tags: ada, josephus

I'm trying to run this code, but something is going wrong with the line:

```
Soldiers (Number_Of_Soldiers) := Soldier_Type'(Name=>new String'(Line(1..Length)), Alive=>True);
```

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you so much!

```
--Josephus Problem

with Ada.Text_IO,Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada;

procedure Josephus is

    type String_Pointer is access String;

    type Soldier_Type is record
       Name  : String_Pointer;
       Alive : Boolean;
    end record;

    Max_Number_Of_Soldiers: constant := 10;
    Number_Of_Soldiers    : Integer range 0..Max_Number_Of_Soldiers := 0;

    -- start with 0 to facilitate modular arithmetic
    Soldiers: array (0..Max_Number_Of_Soldiers-1) of Soldier_Type;

    procedure Next (Index: in out Integer; Interval: Positive) is
    begin
       for I in 1..Interval loop
          loop
            Index := (Index + 1) mod Number_Of_Soldiers;
            exit when Soldiers(Index).Alive;
          end loop;
       end loop;
    end Next;

    Interval : Integer;
    Man      : Integer := Soldiers'First;

begin

     -- get interval from the standard input
     Integer_Text_IO.Get (Interval);
     Text_IO.Skip_Line;
     Text_IO.Put ("Skip every ");
     Integer_Text_IO.Put (Interval, Width=>1);
     Text_IO.Put_Line (" soldiers.");

     -- get names (one per line) from the standard input
    declare

        Line: String (1..10);
        Length: Integer;


    begin
       while not (Text_IO.End_Of_File) loop
          Text_IO.Get_Line (Line, Length);
      Soldiers (Number_Of_Soldiers) := Soldier_Type'(Name=>new String'(Line(1..Length)), Alive=>True);
          Number_Of_Soldiers := Number_Of_Soldiers + 1;
       end loop;
    end;



    for I in 1..Number_Of_Soldiers-1 loop
        Soldiers(Man).Alive := False;
        Text_IO.Put (Soldiers(Man).Name.all);
        Text_IO.Put_Line (" commits suicide.");
        Next (Man, Interval);
    end loop;

     Text_IO.Put (Soldiers(Man).Name.all);
     Text_IO.Put_Line (" is the last.");

end Josephus;
```

Comment: "index check failed" means you have an array index that is out of range for the array.  Maybe you have more lines of input than can fit in the Soldiers array?  Your input loop doesn't have any logic to check whether there's too much input.  Maybe you should add a statement to output Number_Of_Soldiers just before the line where you get the exception.

Comment: Ok, I see. But, to be honest, unfortunately I have no idea how to do this!

Comment: `Text_IO.Put_Line("Number_Of_Soldiers=" & Integer'Image(Number_Of_Soldiers));`.  Or if you're using GNAT, `Text_IO.Put_Line("Number_Of_Soldiers=" & Number_Of_Soldiers'Img);`.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but you are not actually using a modular type like you say you are in your comment. Therefore you should declare Number_of_Soldiers_type as mod 10 (look up the syntax elsewhere), This will impact the usage of Soldiers, Interval, Man, and most importantly Number_Of_Soldiers. This may end up correcting your indexing problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the line

```
Max_Number_Of_Soldiers: constant := 10;
```

Obviously the number specified needs to be more than the maximum possible number of entries in your input!

The problem of unbounded input data sets is one reason to look at using [Ada.Containers.Vectors](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html) instead of arrays.